# Confused about the diff between /etc/sysctl.conf vs /etc/security/limits.conf

Tags: ubuntu, ulimit, sysctl

I am on an Ubuntu18.04.1 bionic VM in the Azure cloud. I am trying to set the maximum number of file descriptors at the system level. 
When I initially logged in and ran `ulimit -n` I get a value of 1024. So I checked the `/etc/security/limits.conf`, but there was no configuration in it. So I thought maybe its configured that way in `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`, so when I checked that out it was set to 1426416. So question 1: Where is 1024 coming from?

I was able to change it by setting some entries in `/etc/security/limits.conf` for `nofile` for * and root domains and I bumped it to 65536 and now `ulimit -n` reflects it. So my question no 2: What is purpose of the entry in `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`? Which I think can be set using `sysctl.conf`

Answer (score 1):

The file /etc/security/limits.conf is used to configure pam_limits and only affects users and services that start through the PAM stack.

/proc/sys/fs/file-max is defined by the kernel sysctl and is the setting for processes started by the OS.

You can also set the file limit in a systemd service by adding LimitNOFILE=1024 to the unit file.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is 1024 coming from?

This is the kernel’s [default limit for the number of open files](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.12/source/include/uapi/linux/fs.h#L37), per process. This is one of the [resource limits](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) which can be set for each process.

> What is purpose of the entry in `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`?

`file-max` specifies [the maximum number of file handles](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html#file-max-file-nr), for the whole system. Once this limit is reached, no process will be able to open a file, regardless of its own per-process limit.

`nr_open`, in the same directory, specifies the maximum [per-process limit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html#nr-open). The actual value used is the resource limit (see above); this determines what the maximum resource limit can be.

Comment: Very clear thank you!